# Performance of DataInputStream\DataOutputStream

Tags: java, performance, io, buffering

I am currently using a buffered streams to read write some files. In between I do some mathematical processing where a symbol is a byte.

To read :

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(outputname)
input.read(byte[] b,int off,int len)
```

To write :

```
OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(
                           new FileOutputStream(outputname),
                           OUTPUTBUFFERSIZE
                       )
output.write((byte)byteinsideaint);
```

Now I need to add some header data, and to support short symbols too. I want to use  `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` to avoid converting other types to bytes myself and I am wondering if what is their performance.

Do I need to use

```
OutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(
                             new BufferedOutputStream(
                                  new FileOutputStream(outputname),
                                  OUTPUTBUFFERSIZE
                             ) 
                       );
```

to keep the advantages of the data buffering or it is good enough to use

```
OutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(
                           new FileOutputStream(outputname)
                       )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add `BufferedOutputStream` in between. [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) does not implement any caching (which is good: separation of concerns) and its performance will be very poor without caching the underlying `OutputStream`. Even the simplest methods like [`writeInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt(int)) can result in four separate disk writes.

As far as I can see only [`write(byte[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int)) and [`writeUTF(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) are writing data in one `byte[]` chunk. Others write primitive values (like `int` or `double`) byte-by-byte.

Comment: This totally helped my day. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely need the BufferedOutputStream in the middle.

I appreciate your concern about the performance, and I have 2 suggestions:

1. Shrink your streams with java compression. Useful article can be found [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84515/smaller-is-better-8211-shrink-your-world-with-java-compression-apis/).
2. Use composition instead of inheritance (which is recommended practice anyway). Create a Pipe which contains a PipedInputStream and a PipedOutputStream connected to each other, with getInputStream() and getOutputStream() methods.You can't directly pass the Pipe object to something needing a stream, but you can pass the return value of it's get methods to do it.

Comment: Thanks. By the requirements of my task I must not compress tough

Comment: GZip*Stream has huge problems in java, though, since it's using a lot of memory through native calls. LZ-4 is probably better.